# Display array not the way I want

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array in place

```
$array = 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cnt_name] => germany
            [ent_func] => sec
            [COUNT(*)] => 31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cnt_name] => germany
            [ent_func] => Coach
            [COUNT(*)] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cnt_name] => germany
            [ent_func] => officer
            [COUNT(*)] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cnt_name] => france
            [ent_func] => manager
            [COUNT(*)] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cnt_name] => france
            [ent_func] => sec
            [COUNT(*)] => 10
        )

)
```

What i need is to output the following table.

```
Country Name     sec   Coach   officer   
germany           31     1      2        
france            10     0      0         
--------------------------------------
Total             41     0      2
```

I have tried as follows, But the output is wrong...

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>  
                <th><?= _('Name')?></th>
                <th><?= _('Sec')?></th> 
                <th><?= _('Coach')?></th>
                <th><?= _('officer')?></th>   
            </tr>  
            <?php foreach($array as $sbc) {?>
                <tr>   
                    <td><?=$sbc['cnt_name']?></td>  
                    <td><?php $sbc['ent_func'] == 'BX' ? 0 : ''?></td> 
                    <td><?=$sbc['COUNT(*)']?></td>   
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            <tr>   
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><span class="badge badge-info"><?=$summBoxer + $summOffic?></span></td>  
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Some one help Please?

Comment: How is it "wrong"?  What does that display?  You are aware you have 4 headers (`<th>`) and only 3 `<td>`s, right?

Comment: I recommend you not to use the PHP shorthand syntax. It's `<?php` and not `<?=`. Unless you're PHP >= 5.4 where `<?=` is available regardless of the short_open_tags ini parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `echo`

```
 <td><?=($sbc['ent_func'] == 'BX') ? 0 : ''?></td>
```

Comment: `<?=` is the same thing as `<?php echo`.

Comment: Yes it is. Both are true.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to add `echo $sbc['ent_func']`

```
<td><?php echo $sbc['ent_func'] == 'BX' ? 0 : '';?></td>
```

Or

```
<?=($sbc['ent_func'] == 'BX') ? 0 : '';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one `<td></td`> in your second `<tr>` and still in the Total you have only one `<td></td>`, but in your index table:

```
<tr>  
    <th><?= _('Name')?></th>
    <th><?= _('Sec')?></th> 
    <th><?= _('Coach')?></th>
    <th><?= _('officer')?></th>   
</tr>
```

there are 4 td's, you can either balance it with a colspan or with placing the proper number of td's. As i can see in the output you want you have to balance them.